# Understanding how the Nernst statement of the Third Law implies the Planck statement

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, temperature, cryogenics

I am reading Callen who, up to and including where I am at (Chapter 11), treats thermodynamics as a classical theory with only the maximum entropy postulate for isolated systems sprinkled in as a "theorem" of statistical mechanics.

At any rate, in Chapter 11 Callen proves the Nernst statement of the Third Law:

> In any isothermal process at $T = 0$, the change in entropy $\Delta S$ between the initial and final statements is also $0$.

This statement can be succinctly written as:

> The $T = 0$ isotherm is also an adiabat.

The Planck statement goes further, and says

> The $T = 0$ isotherm is also an adiabat with the value $S = 0$.

I am trying to understand this leap within the framework of classical thermodyanmics. With respect to this leap, Callen says the following:

> In the thermodynamic context there is no a priori meaning to the absolute value of the entropy. The Planck restatement has significance only in its statistical mechanical interpretation, to which we shall turn in Part II. We have, in fact, chosen the Planck form of the postulate rather than the Nernst form largely because of the pithiness of its statement (rather than because of any additional thermodynamic content).

Am I therefore to understand the leap as saying that since (per the rigorously true -- within the classical thermodynamics framework -- Nernst statement) the $T=0$ isotherm is also an adiabat, and since the entropy function is also unspecified, we can simply *choose* to assign this adiabat as $S = 0$. And then that it is only once an investigation emerges from statistical mechanics that we find that $S = 0$ at $T = 0$ is not a choice but a theorem which we are forced into?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think you are interpreting the Nernst statement incorrectly. It says let $T$ be constant, and now consider $\Delta S$ (between two states on that isotherm). Now take the limit as $T \to 0$. This is different than what you are describing, I think? @hyportnex

Comment: you are right, probably

Comment: The real content of Planck's formulation is that at $T=0$, entropy is the same constant for every thermodynamic system. The value $0$ is just a (very) convenient choice.

Comment: I see, @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90. So, to confirm, you agree with what I've wrote? And that the Planck statement only carries more content once thermodynamic entropy has been connected to statistical mechanical notions?

Comment: S(T=0)=0 is a convenient convention even at the statistical mechanics level. There is enough freedom in the connection between entropy and the number of microstates to accommodate a "within an arbitrary constant". The point is that thermodynamic entropy is always defined within an additive constant.

Comment: Thank you Giorgio! I'd be delighted to accept the above if you post as an answer!